# Is there a way to write programs for photoshop cs5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

If I want to write some code for doing photoshop tasks, how would i do that?  What I'm trying to do is have a program that will parse psd files (in photoshop) and go through the groups to check for things in the name, then combine certain layers, and other stuff like that, using variable counters and whatnot.  So like a very customizable action.  Except I want it to be able to make decisions, not just do a static set of operations.  Any points in the right direction? (even just what it's called is okay, i can google)

Comment: ooh i thought a script was just a list of commands.  guess i'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have already started by searching for [photoshop script](http://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop%20script)? Did you see [this page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)?

> ooh i thought a script was just a list of commands. guess i'll look into that.

Oh, boy, I hope that comment doesn't restart the age old debate about [scripting vs programming languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46137/what-is-the-main-difference-between-scripting-languages-and-programming-languages).  You will not from the link you can use at least vbscript, javascript, and applescript.  Given that Photoshop provides a COM interface, you probably should be able to use any language you want.